# How to execute parallel-loop in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, parallel-processing

To calculate the distance between two points (latitude, longitude), implemented a function of haversine formula. To improve performance, I want to execute this for-loop in parallel. Please comment how to do that?

```
  for (var _i = 0; _i < count; _i++) { 
            var _dummy: number = haversine(36.12, -86.67,
              data[_i].position.lat, data[_i].position.lng);
          }
```

A complete list of source code for reference.

```
//There are 6200 points in the JSON file
import data from './json/test.json';

let radians = function (degree: number) {

  // degrees to radians
  let rad: number = degree * Math.PI / 180;

  return rad;
}

const haversine = (lat1: number, lon1: number, lat2: number, lon2: number) => {

  let dlat, dlon, a, c, R: number;

  R = 6372.8; // km
  dlat = radians(lat2 - lat1);
  dlon = radians(lon2 - lon1);
  lat1 = radians(lat1);
  lat2 = radians(lat2);
  a = Math.sin(dlat / 2) * Math.sin(dlat / 2) + Math.sin(dlon / 2) * Math.sin(dlon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2)
  c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
  return R * c;
}

let test = function () {
  const keys = Object.keys(data);

  let count: number = keys.length;
  for (var _i = 0; _i < count; _i++) {
    var _dummy: number = haversine(
      36.12, -86.67, data[_i].position.lat, data[_i].position.lng);
  }

}
```

Comment: There are lots of way to accomplish this task. If you use redux, you can simply use redux-saga (or RxJS, thunk, async-await functions) for your async operations. I generally use redux-saga. Basically you need to fire an action and in saga function you can fetch the action and calculate lng-lat then set to the reducer

Comment: @KaanÖner None of that will be processed in paralled. You will need workers for it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am studying "promise" and find this    package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async.

Comment: @madeinQuant Neither promises nor async.js make anything run in parallel. They only ease the usage of things that already are asynchronous. For parallel processing, you would need to spawn worker threads.